# Why am I getting this error with the R function gsynth?

Tags: r, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am trying to generate synthetic controls with the gsynth function. I have an outcome (Y), with a binary treatment assignment (D), no covariates, and then an "id" number for each unique group and then a "time" ranging from 1-11 time periods. Whenever I run it however, I keep getting this error. Could anyone help out?

```
out <- gsynth(Y ~ D, data = data6, index = c("id","time"), force = "two-way", 
   CV = FALSE, r = c(0,5), se = TRUE, inference = "parametric", nboots = 1000, min.T0 = 6)
```

> Parallel computing ... Bootstrapping ... ... Error in
>   `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = iname[which(out$tr == 1)]) :    attempt
>   to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The reason for this error is that the "best" solution is r*=0, so the optimal number of factors is zero. Therefore, the result is empty. Although I don't really know what causes this issue, there's an easy way to solve it:

In the gsynth function, don't set r to r = c(0, 5), but instead set r = c(1, 5). This forces the gsynth function to ignore the no-factor-solution and the result can never be empty.

I know this probably doesn't solve the "deeper" issue that causes the error but at least it's a way to at least get a result from the function.